# Whats a reasonable popular science way to describe the unit $\rm T*ha*y$?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, units, si-units

I'm doing an popular science article on saving the climate through photosynthesis. For this I need to use the convenient unit ha*y (and because we've got so much area on the planet I want to do `T*ha*y`). I can of course use `km^2` instead of `ha`, but that doesn't reduce the complexity. Please don't suggest anything about miles or football fields, I'm from Europe.

Pretty much everybody understands enough about `kWh` as a unit to some extent, but when I do `Thay`, or punctuated `T*ha*y`, I get blank stares. The concept of sequestering carbon at a certain rate per area for a certain amount of time goes down well, but as soon as I use a unit for it, the lights go out.

I'm sure the physics isn't very challenging at all, it's mostly my way with people that's a hurdle. I hope that is appropriate for this forum. Tips?

Comment: Can you clarify the units you are abbreviating?  I think you mean (tera-hectare)*(years), is that correct?  What is the actual physical quantity you are discussing?  Area*Time is not a common quantity I'm familiar with

Comment: I'm confused by your notation.  Do you mean "terahectare-years"?  That's a weird amalgam of prefixes, since "hect-" is already a metric prefix meaning 100x.  Or do you mean something else?

Comment: What is this unit supposed to express? I parse it as a product of area (hectares) and time (years), with a Tera- prefix (in which case the first multiplication should not be there). In any case I recommend using $\mathrm{km^2}$ over $\mathrm{ha}$.

Comment: 1 tera hectare year is equivalent to 1 Europe millennium.

Comment: The total land area of Earth is only about 50 Gha. Nobody will have any idea how big a Tha is even if they can work out what the unit means.

Comment: Just to show how non-obvious your unit is, from the post title I assumed you were talking about *temperature* $\times$ area $\times$ some sort of *length* denoted by $y$ - i.e. "the heat energy in some (probably very large) volume of space".

Comment: I fixed it based on the suggestions here. Much obliged! You're all welcome to read and comment on the draft in case you're interested in crazy climate fixes: https://docs.google.com/document/d/11o8CZceeow_D-PlDeE5oDZenWjU5Ztgv7sGZRVpdfDw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you meant "terahectare" by Tha, that is not a valid unit at all.  You are generally not allowed to use more than one metric prefix on a single unit, and ha already has the "hecto" (h) prefix attached to the area unit "are" (a).  (See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hectare#Conversions)  The symbol - I won't call it a unit - Tha - has both a tera and a hecto prefix.

Ultimately if you want to "humanize" the unit for general readership, it will be more important to compare to something they know.  You said you're from Europe, so maybe compare to the size of the continent or to one of the countries?

Comment: wonderful point, I was actually stuck at that one. Thanks. Pm^2 is odd, but not more so than Tha. And more correct for sure. I'll go for a comparable example and puzzle that into the story. Anything with more than five 0's is generally not great for understanding.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct, because it directly defuses the incorrect premise in the question. I solved my problem by calculating what we need to do per person. Each person has about 1ha to work with, and needs to sequester about 200 tons on that area asap to fix the planet. Thanks for your awesome help!

Answer (score 4):

There's a reason why popular science articles use units of football fields for area and elephants for mass.  This gives the reader an intuitive sense of scale.  This all breaks down when the numbers get big enough.  One million elephants is just as hard to conceive as one billion kilograms.  The key is to find comparisons that are easier to wrap one's brain around.

There's also the problem of readability.  If a quantity [10 Thay] looks strange to a bunch of self selected physics enthusiasts, it's going to be hard for the general public to understand.

I would state things in base scale units and comparison units.  The rate of CO$_2$ absorption is X kg per m$^2$ (or km$^2$) per year.  That's comprehensible, but what's 1 kg of CO$_2$?  How much CO$_2$ is in the atmosphere right now?  How much is emitted per year?  How much is emitted in the EU?  In Germany?  Readers need context.

I have no intuition about a tera-hectare.  I do have intuition about "the entire surface area of Germany".  A statement like "it would take $N$ Germanies of surface area to reabsorb the actual yearly emissions of Germany in one year" is something I can understand.

You are trying to teach your readers about photosynthesis and climate.  Don't lose the message by trying to teach them dimensional analysis at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for the valid points. Once the true problem is understood, also from the comments on the question ;) It is easier to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with $\text{ha}$ for [hectare](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/hectare) is that it is uncommon in physics, being typically used in agriculture and more generally in economics. Geography clearly uses $\text{m}^2$ and $\text{km}^2$.
Then $\text{year}$ (which you expect to shorten to $\text{y}$) is ill-defined, as there are (from a physical geography perspective) more types of years (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year#Astronomical_years)). Most likely you mean calendar/civil year (1st of Jan. 0h to 1St. of Jan 0h, no leap year taken into account).

So combining a physics/informatics prefix such as Tera ($\text{T}$) with a relatively unknown unit in physics and with an ill-defined unit of time can't get anywhere.

Comment: The ill-definedness of "year" is a pretty minor issue here, it seems to me.  I doubt that the ambiguity of what is meany by a "year" is what's tripping up non-experts when they see this combined unit.  I also doubt that the numbers for carbon absorption in a $\text{km}^2$ of land are precise enough to make the distinction between the various definitions of a year meaningful.

Comment: to reach agronomists and people in the streets we need to talk hectares/acres/years. I hate that that's not SI as much as anyone here, but there's nothing for it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Does the amount of time actually matter?  If you are talking about total amount of carbon sequestered, do your examples actually require you to compare (for example) 5 square kilometers of forest that absorb carbon for one year vs. 1 square kilometer that absorbs carbon for five years?  If not, then it might work just to compare the amounts of carbon absorbed annually per hectare.

In terms of the kilowatt-hours analogy:  it's true that your electrical bill is in kilowatt-hours.  But if you're comparing a 100-W incandescent lightbulb to a 20-W compact fluorescent, and you assume that the light will be turned on for the same number of hours no matter which option you pick, you don't need to know how many hours it will be on to know that the 100-W one uses 5 times more energy.

Comment: It does. There's about 1Pkg too much CO2 in the atmosphere. The article is about how much of the planet we need for how much time to fix that. Balancing time with area is the main point…